# How to insert tag into ref in react-native?

Tags: react-native

Now I am going to insert `<AgoraView ... />` into `<DeepARView.../>`.
So I want to replace `this.deepARView` with `<AgoraView />`
I am not sure how to insert this into `DeepARView` grammatically.
This is my code. (Integrating with Video chatting and AR SDK. So I want to mask off the face of the person on the other end of the line)

```
<View style={{ height: dimensions.height }}>
    <AgoraView style={{ flex: 1 }}
        remoteUid={this.state.peerIds[0]} mode={1} />
    {
        this.state.permissionsGranted ?
            <DeepARView
                onEventSent={this.onEventSent}
                ref={ref => this.deepARView = ref}
                style={{ width: width, height: '100%' }}
            />
            :
            null
    }
</View>
```

Is it possible to add?
If possible how to insert this into MainView as ref?

Answer (score 0):

**update**

Do you mean achieve something like this in [example](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-RN-Quickstart)?

```js
 this.state.peerIds.length > 0                   //view for videostream
? <AgoraView style={styles.full}
  remoteUid={this.state.peerIds[0]} mode={1} />
: <View>
  <Text style={styles.noUserText}> No users connected </Text>
 </View>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I modified code again.
Could you please help me again?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not really understand what you want with `this.deepARView`, with the `ref => {this.deepARView = ref}` , you could use it in the component render everywhere with `this.deepARView.something` after that , but I think you wanna mask a view over another, so maybe one of this could try?

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Then I tried both method, but all failed. How to...?

Comment: I'm not really understand how `DeepARView` and `AgoraView` worked, which one is mask and should be inside another view?

Comment: Is there any package about `AgoraView` or `DeepARView` ?

Comment: react-native-agora

Comment: And DeepARView is SDK.

Comment: AgoraView is video chatting tag. DeepARView is face mask filter tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215270/discussion-between-satelbill-and-).